# finding multiple within-string matches in R

Tags: r, regex

As the title says, I am looking to locate and count multiple matches of a target string within a larger string. For example:

```
# looking for 
target <- "zoo"
# in this
word <- "zoozoo"
```

I have tried a few different things such as:

```
regexpr(target, word)
```

and

```
regmatches(word, regexpr(target, word))
```

But neither of these finds both of the substrings i.e. `"zoo"` and `"zoo"`. I am trying to write something that will find and count all of the matches, there will be multiple in what I am trying to do.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `str_count` to count all the matched occurrences.

```
library(stringr)
str_count(word, target)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need both the positions of the substrings and the count, you might try

```
positions <- unlist(gregexpr(target, word))
count <- length(positions)
```